Keras model.fit() not working: `tf.data.Dataset` only supports Python-style iteration in eager mode or within tf.function."
This code used to work:
 # fit network
    history = model.fit(train_x, train_y,
                        validation_split=0.2,
              epochs=epochs,
#               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
              batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose,
#               validation_data=(vali_x, vali_y),
              validation_steps=validation_steps,
             callbacks = keras_callbacks
                       )

But now after upgrading TensorFlow and Keras, it returns error: tf.data.Dataset only supports Python-style iteration in eager mode or within tf.function.
The way train_x and train_y are defined as
# split a univariate dataset into train/test sets
def split_dataset(data, n_output, hold_out_period):
    # split into standard weeks
    train, test = data[:-hold_out_period], data[-hold_out_period:]
    # restructure into windows of weekly data
    train = np.array(np.split(train, len(train)/n_output))
    test = np.array(np.split(test, len(test)/n_output))
    return train, test

# convert history into inputs and outputs
def to_supervised(train, n_input, n_output):
    # flatten data
    data = train.reshape((train.shape[0]*train.shape[1], train.shape[2]))
    X, y = list(), list()
    in_start = 0
    # step over the entire history one time step at a time
    for _ in range(len(data)):
        # define the end of the input sequence
        in_end = in_start + n_input
        out_end = in_end + n_output
        # ensure we have enough data for this instance
        if out_end <= len(data):
            X.append(data[in_start:in_end, :])
            y.append(data[in_end:out_end, 0])
        # move along one time step
        in_start += 1
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

# train the model
def build_model(train, n_input, n_output, version, model_type, cnn_filter, cnn_kernel, lstm_initial_neuron, repeat):
    # prepare data
    train_x, train_y = to_supervised(train, n_input, n_output)

#     train_y = np.asarray(train_y).astype('float32')
#     train_x = np.asarray(train_x).astype('float32')
    # define parameters
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 1000, 32
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2], train_y.shape[1]
    # reshape output into [samples, timesteps, features]
    train_y = train_y.reshape((train_y.shape[0], train_y.shape[1], 1))
    train_y = train_y.reshape(-1)

model_path = 'kbb_cnn_lstm_dts.keras'

    keras_callbacks = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                        min_delta=0, patience=30,
                                                        verbose=verbose, mode='min'),
                       tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_path,monitor='val_loss',
                                                          save_best_only=True,
                                                          mode='min', verbose=verbose)]
    steps_per_epoch = len(train_x)//batch_size

    validation_steps = (len(train_x)*0.2)//batch_size

How should I fix this error?
I have tried couple of ways but it didn't work out.

Something is missing at any point you load your data into a tf.data.Dataset instance.

Could you be more specific about this? My code is feeding train_x and train_y as nparray, and I am not exactly clear about when the data is converted into a tf.data.Dataset

which version of tensorflow are you using?

I was using 2.16.1

What does print(tf.executing_eagerly())  give you?

Also check to ensure model.fit(..., ....) are numpy arrays [ train_x & train_y ]
